# Probability of two subsamples containing overlapping data

Tags: probability, sampling, sample-size

I am trying to estimate the amount of overlapping data between two subsamples within a sample. I have the sample size, the sizes of the two subsamples, and I know the correlation between the two subsamples' sizes (I have many samples to calculate the correlation with). I do not have the raw data, just these aggregate numbers. I am not sure how to best go about finding the estimated overlap. I am trying to do this with all samples, but here is one sample as an example:

Sample size: 13,672
Subsample A size: 12,530
Subsample B size: 2,527
The Pearson correlation between the percentage of the Sample that is in group A (size A/Sample size) and the percentage of the Sample that is in group B (size B/Sample size) (for all my samples) is -.93

How can I best calculate the overlap between A and B using this correlation, or what other data would I need to be able to effectively do this?

The closest thing I've been able to find is the Hypergeometric Distribution, where I have a sample of 13,672, and 12,530 of those are contained in subsample A. If I selected 2,527 (the size of subsample B) of them, how many would be in subsample A? The problem is, this assumes the selection is random, but the subsample B isn't a random selection, it is a secondary group whose saturation of the entire sample correlates negatively with subsample A's saturation of the sample.

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. What do you mean by "*the ratio of A to the Sample*"?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the confusion, I just meant the % of the sample that is subsample A, and the % of the sample that is subsample B

Comment: Since the subsamples are not random, there is little we can tell you unless you provide details of how these subsamples are obtained.